# Subtracting from a number value column and limiting the result to zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I am trying to see if I can subract a number from a col, but if the number is negative after the subtraction to limit the output to 0 and nothing less or negative.

For ex. col in DF looks like

```
Mins | new_col
 5.0    2.0
 1.0    0.0
 2.0    0.0
 0.5    0.0
 1.2    0.0
 4.0    1.0
```

if I want to create a new column that gives me the same values but subtracts 3 from each value in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df['new_col'] = df['Mins'].sub(3).clip(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract and then [`clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) using:

```
df['new_col'] = np.clip(df['Mins']-3, 0, None)
#alternative df['new_col'] = np.clip(df['Mins'].sub(3), 0, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

this solves it.. using [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['Mins']-3 > 0, df['Mins']-3, 0)
```

**Output**

```
   Mins  new_col
0   5.0      2.0
1   1.0      0.0
2   2.0      0.0
3   0.5      0.0
4   1.2      0.0
5   4.0      1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by simple `for` loop. Store the input values in list `list1`.

`list2=[]
for value in list1:
        sub=value-3.0
        if sub <= 0: list2.append(0.0)
        else: list2.append(sub)
print list2`